# A holomorphic function $f:D\rightarrow D$ such that $\mid f(z^2)\mid\geq \mid f(z)\mid$ for all $z$ must be constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I ran into this reading some Complex stuff for fluid dynamics, and it seems so simple but it's got me stuck. $D$ stands for the unit disk.

Since $\mid z \mid<1$, then  $\mid z^2\mid \leq \mid z \mid$. So $$\mid f(z^2)\mid\geq \mid f(z)\mid$$ is trying to tell me that points closer to the origin are being sent further out, and geometrically it feels like a holomorphic function that is not constant shouldn't be able to do that, but I don't quite see why.

I know the Maximum Modulus principle is usually the way to get constants out of holomorphic maps. Also, it must be easy to show that $\mid f(z) \mid \leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$, so that I also have the Schwarz Lemma at hand to give me $\mid f(z) \mid \leq \mid z\mid$. Playing with this, however, I've only managed to get the fact that $$\mid f(z)\mid \leq \mid f(z^2)\mid\leq \mid z^2 \mid\leq \mid z\mid$$ Would this be helpful in finding a maximum inside the unit disk to use Max/Mod to get a constant out of $f$?

Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The hypotheses imply $\sup_{|z|\le 1/2}\,|f| \le \sup_{|z|\le 1/4}\,|f|.$

Comment: Thanks. So, unless $f$ is constant, this is a contradiction since $\{z : \mid z \mid \leq \frac{1}{2}\}$ contains $ \{z : \mid z \mid \leq \frac{1}{4}\}$

Comment: That should do it.  +1

Comment: And being $f$ holomorphic is irrelevant. The important fact is that every complex number is a square.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla $f(z) = 1-|z|^2$ satisfies the inquality but is not constant.

Comment: True, your argument proves that $|f|$ is constant. If $f$ is holomorphic, $|f|$ constant $\implies f$ constant.